# vb.net program running single space CMD commands and returning output

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, cmd

So my issue is with code I found from the web. The code works well with commands with only a single space in the form `Command Argument`.

I would like to edit the code so that I may add options to my command like `youtube-dl [COMMAND] -i [OPTIONS] URL [URL]`. That command would have 3 spaces but the code only supports one space.

How would the code need to be edited to support multiple arguments to send to a command process?

```
Public Class Form1
Private psi As ProcessStartInfo
Private cmd As Process
Private Delegate Sub InvokeWithString(ByVal text As String)
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Folder, URL As String
    Folder = txtFolder.Text
    URL = txtUrl.Text
    txtCommand.Text = "C:\Users\Merskies\Desktop\Youtube-dl\youtube-dl.exe -i -o D:\YoutubeDL\" & Folder & "\%%(title)s.%%(ext)s " & URL
    Try
        cmd.Kill()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    txtOutput.Clear()
    If txtCommand.Text.Contains(" ") Then
        psi = New ProcessStartInfo(txtCommand.Text.Split(" ")(0), txtCommand.Text.Split(" ")(1))
    Else
        psi = New ProcessStartInfo(txtCommand.Text$)
    End If
    Dim systemencoding As System.Text.Encoding
    System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TextInfo.OEMCodePage)
    With psi
        .UseShellExecute = False
        .RedirectStandardError = True
        .RedirectStandardOutput = True
        .RedirectStandardInput = True
        .CreateNoWindow = True
        .StandardOutputEncoding = systemencoding
        .StandardErrorEncoding = systemencoding
    End With
    cmd = New Process With {.StartInfo = psi, .EnableRaisingEvents = True}
    AddHandler cmd.ErrorDataReceived, AddressOf Async_Data_Received
    AddHandler cmd.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf Async_Data_Received
    cmd.Start()
    cmd.BeginOutputReadLine()
    cmd.BeginErrorReadLine()
End Sub
Private Sub Async_Data_Received(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataReceivedEventArgs)
    Me.Invoke(New InvokeWithString(AddressOf Sync_Output), e.Data)
End Sub
Private Sub Sync_Output(ByVal text As String)
    txtOutput.AppendText(text & Environment.NewLine)
    txtOutput.ScrollToCaret()
End Sub
End Class
```

[My Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yv16P.png)

Comment: Please copy and paste the code into the question as text. No graphics. No external links. Be sure it is an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I am trying to get the code to fit in a code box. I just joined the community and this is my first post sorry.

Comment: Welcome to SO. When you come into a new community, it is good to be familiar with any and all covenants, conditions, and restrictions that might apply. https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: this line here is giving you trouble psi = New ProcessStartInfo(txtCommand.Text.Split(" ")(0), txtCommand.Text.Split(" ")(1)) It will only return the first switch/arg

Comment: @Merskies look here and look for Arguments about 1/4 from the top of the page. This is the part that interest you. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo(v=vs.110).aspx pass all of them instead of only one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Folder, URL As String
    Folder = txtFolder.Text
    URL = txtUrl.Text
    txtCommand.Text = "C:\Users\Merskies\Desktop\Youtube-dl\youtube-dl.exe"
    dim Arguments as string ="-i -o D:\YoutubeDL\" & Folder & "\%%(title)s.%%(ext)s " & URL
    Try
        cmd.Kill()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    txtOutput.Clear()
    If Arguments <> "" Then
        psi = New ProcessStartInfo(txtCommand.Text, Arguments)
    Else
        psi = New ProcessStartInfo(txtCommand.Text)
    End If
    Dim systemencoding As System.Text.Encoding
    System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TextInfo.OEMCodePage)
    With psi
        .UseShellExecute = False
        .RedirectStandardError = True
        .RedirectStandardOutput = True
        .RedirectStandardInput = True
        .CreateNoWindow = True
        .StandardOutputEncoding = systemencoding
        .StandardErrorEncoding = systemencoding
    End With
    cmd = New Process With {.StartInfo = psi, .EnableRaisingEvents = True}
    AddHandler cmd.ErrorDataReceived, AddressOf Async_Data_Received
    AddHandler cmd.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf Async_Data_Received
    cmd.Start()
    cmd.BeginOutputReadLine()
    cmd.BeginErrorReadLine()
End Sub
Private Sub Async_Data_Received(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataReceivedEventArgs)
    Me.Invoke(New InvokeWithString(AddressOf Sync_Output), e.Data)
End Sub
Private Sub Sync_Output(ByVal text As String)
    txtOutput.AppendText(text & Environment.NewLine)
    txtOutput.ScrollToCaret()
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You should take the habit of naming your control as you create them. It's a good a habit not to lose. Easier to debug when you know what button1 does just by it's name.